# Module '"@testing-library/react-native"' has no exported member 'waitForElement'

Tags: react-native, expo, jest-expo

Not sure why this is happening when the docs say it's okay to use this: https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/functions/%40testing-library%2Freact-native/waitForElement

[image]

App.test.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { waitFor, waitForElement } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import App from './App';

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe('App initialized', () => {
  it('has 1 child', async () => {
    const Element = await waitForElement(() => renderer.create(<App />).toJSON() as any);
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(Element).not.toBeNull();
      expect(Element.children.length).toBe(1);
    });
  });
});
```

App.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { NavigationConductor } from '@app/navigation';
import { useLoadingStore } from '@app/stores';

export default function App() {
  // variables
  const { appStartInitializeData } = useLoadingStore(store => store);

  // setup
  useEffect(() => {
    appStartInitializeData();
  }, []);

  // render
  return <NavigationConductor />;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `waitFor` instead. `waitForElement` has been renamed a while ago.

See [Migration to 7.0](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/migration-v7) for details.